# Calculating an average number from three columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate an average number from three columns but only include the column in the calculation if column is not null and is bigger than 0;

for example the average usually is

```
(column1 + column2 + column3) / 3
```

but if column3 is null or 0 then it will be

```
(column1 + column2 + column3) / 2 or (column1 + column2 ) / 2
```

I have this sol far but it is not complete. the average is wrong when one of the columns is 0 (0 is default)

```
SELECT movie.title,
 movie.imdbrating,
 movie.metacritic,
 tomato.rating,
 ((imdbrating + metacritic + tomato.rating)/3) as average
FROM movie, tomato
WHERE movie.imdbid = tomato.imdbid
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Did you try with the `AVG` native functions ? Maybe it ignores NULL values

Comment: @Asenar How could that possibly be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fixing the rest of the query to use table aliases and proper `join` syntax.  But the `case` statements are what you really need:

```
SELECT m.title, m.imdbrating, m.metacritic,
       t.rating,
       ((case when imdbrating > 0 then imdbrating else 0 end) +
        (case when metacritic > 0 then metacritic else 0 end) +
        (case when t.rating > 0 then t.rating else 0 end) +
       ) / nullif(coalesce((imdbrating > 0), 0) + coalesce((metacritic > 0), 0) + coalesce((t.rating > 0), 0)), 0)
FROM movie m JOIN
     tomato t
     ON m.imdbid = t.imdbid;
```

The denominator is using a convenient MySQL extension where booleans are treated as 0 or 1 in a numeric context.  The `nullif()` returns `NULL` if no rating meets the conditions.  And, the `> 0` is is not true for `NULL` values.

Comment: What about Negative values?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  These are not included in the average which is what the OP is asking for.  That seems pretty obvious, though, given the `> 0`.

Comment: ignore my last comment

Comment: `null > 0` will return null not 0. And there are some syntax errors, such as last `+` and miss a `(` after `nullif`.

Comment: My suggestion is using ifnull()

Comment: @JaugarChang . . . The problem would be `NULL` values, not negative values.  I just added `coalesce()` to fix that problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT (IF Column3 IS NULL OR Column3=0, AVG(Column1+Column2), Avg(Column1+Column2+ Column3)) as Result FROM Table
```

**EDIT:**

If any of the tree columns can be nullm, try this:

```
SELECT AVG(IF(Column1 IS NULL,0,Column1)+IF(Column2 IS NULL,0,Column2)+IF(Column3 IS NULL,0,Column3)) as Result FROM Table
```

Comment: what if column1 is null or column2 or both. or all of the columns are null?

Comment: He only mention Column3 as nulleable.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

```
(ifnull(column1,0)+ifnull(column2,0)+ifnull(column3,0))/
nullif((abs(sign(ifnull(column1,0)))
       +abs(sign(ifnull(column2,0)))
       +abs(sign(ifnull(column3,0)))), 0)
```

Can handle Negative values.

[**Demo to test**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/49125)